# How to add angular build with asp.net core build in a dockerfile?

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core

I have created an Asp.Net Core Web API project and a separate Angular App in the same solution. I did not opt for SPA template for separation of concerns. I have been able to dockerize the Asp.Net Core WebAPI build and run steps and have also added angular build. But when I build the dockerfile, I don't see angular/npm build related messages neither are they built. I don't have configured the copy of build output of angular to wwwroot folder, but before that I would like to see my angular app also getting built with Asp.Net Core build. So can anyone help me with this issue. Below is my dockerfile:

```
# ASP.NET CORE BUILD STAGE
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS dotnet-build

WORKDIR /app
COPY    . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /publish


# ANGULAR BUILD
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS ng-build

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ClientApp/package.json /app

RUN npm install
COPY ./ClientApp /app
RUN npm run build --prod


# RUNTIME IMAGE STAGE
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=dotnet-build /publish .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","/publish/DemoApp.dll" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add a reference of your ng-build stage 'image' to the runtime stage 'image', it might run the `npm install` and `ng build --prod` for you.
I think you should update your runtime 'image' stage to something like this:

```
# RUNTIME IMAGE STAGE
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=dotnet-build /publish .
COPY --from=ng-build /dist/ClientApp /publish/wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","/publish/DemoApp.dll" ]
```